# Free SQL formatter tool

Tags: sql, eclipse-plugin, formatter

is there any free SQL formatter tool? I am using http://www.sqlinform.com/ for small queries. It is very good. But free version supports only 100 lines. [TORA](http://torasql.com/) has the feature but it has many issues and I can not customize everything. Any free Eclipse plugins for this?

Comment: SQLinForm now has a free online version without the 100 line limit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) from Oracle is free, supports multiple databases (not just Oracle), and lets you configure how SQL is formatted.

Answer (score 2):

e-texteditor have a snippet can do this.
[image]